# neo4j embeded in java

Tags: java, neo4j

i tried to execute the tutoriel but this error message is keeping to be appears

```
Exception in thread "main" org.neo4j.graphdb.NotInTransactionException
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.persistence.PersistenceManager.getResource(PersistenceManager.java:228)    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.persistence.PersistenceManager.getResource(PersistenceManager.java:228)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.persistence.PersistenceManager.nodeCreate(PersistenceManager.java:155)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeManager.createNode(NodeManager.java:254)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDbImpl.createNode(EmbeddedGraphDbImpl.java:305)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.createNode(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:105)
    at twiapp.embeded.main(embeded.java:37)
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: Can you show us what code you are trying to run?

Comment: public static void main(String args[]) {
    graphDb = new EmbeddedGraphDatabase( path ); 
    registerShutdownHook( graphDb );
    Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx();
    try { 
        tx.success(); 
    }
    finally { 
        tx.finish(); 
    } 
    
    firstNode = graphDb.createNode();
    firstNode.setProperty( "message", "Hello, " );
    secondNode = graphDb.createNode();
    secondNode.setProperty( "message", "World!" );
    relationship = firstNode.createRelationshipTo( secondNode, RelTypes.KNOWS );
    relationship.setProperty( "message", "brave Neo4j " ); 
 }

Comment: with  private static void registerShutdownHook( final GraphDatabaseService graphDb ) {     
     Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook( new Thread()    
     {        @Override        public void run()        
     {            graphDb.shutdown();        }    } ); } 
}

Comment: and          private static final String path="C:/Users/pato/Documents/Neo4j/default.graphdb"; 
        static  GraphDatabaseService graphDb;
        private static enum RelTypes implements RelationshipType {    KNOWS } 
        static Node  firstNode; 
        static Node  secondNode; 
        static Relationship  relationship;

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.neo4j.graphdb.TransactionFailureException: Could not create data source [nioneodb], see nested exception for cause of error
 at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.TxModule.registerDataSource(TxModule.java:153) at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.TxModule.registerDataSource(TxModule.java:153)
 at org.neo4j.kernel.GraphDbInstance.start(GraphDbInstance.java:111)
 at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDbImpl.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDbImpl.java:189)
 at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:79)
 at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.

Comment: can you please put the code examples in your question?

Answer (score 1):

Your code modifying the database needs to run within the transaction:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(path);
        registerShutdownHook(graphDb);
        Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx();
        try {


        firstNode = graphDb.createNode();
        firstNode.setProperty("message", "Hello, ");
        secondNode = graphDb.createNode();
        secondNode.setProperty("message", "World!");
        relationship = firstNode.createRelationshipTo(secondNode, RelTypes.KNOWS);
        relationship.setProperty("message", "brave Neo4j ");

            tx.success();
        } finally {
            tx.finish();
        }
    }
```

Also you should create the embedded database using the provided factory. See tutorial for version 2.1.7 http://neo4j.com/docs/2.1.7/tutorials-java-embedded-hello-world.html